# How to provide default credentials from instance role to Apache Camel SQS Route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, amazon-sqs, aws-credentials

I am using apache camel for reading msg from AWS SQS. It Works exactly as expected when passing AWS AccessKey SecretKey in URI but.. I Don't want to add secret keys in URI I want it to take **default credentials** from Instance Role. I have given SQS permission to my **IAM Role** but don't know how to pass it to camel.

```
 from("aws-sqs://Queue-name?accessKey=....&secretKey=....&region=EU_WEST_1")
    .bean(bean.class, method)
    .toD("https://www.")
```

Please help me in this

Comment: What is the camel version you're using?

Comment: I am using camel 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an LTS release. The last LTS release of Apache Camel is 3.14.x.

For your specific problem have a look at the "useDefaultCredentialsProvider" parameter in the documentation: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/aws2-sqs-component.html

It will follow the order reported in the AWS SDK v2 docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html